# MediaPlayer on Windows 10 XAML Error 'Windows.Media.Streaming.Adaptive.AdaptiveMediaSource' is not registered

Tags: c#, xaml, media-player, windows-10, http-live-streaming

I am getting an error when I am trying to play a HLS url in my Windows10 app, has anyone been having the same issue as I am?

Error that I am getting when calling CreateFromUriAsync:

```
Requested Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Media.Streaming.Adaptive.AdaptiveMediaSource' is not registered.
```

I have the Microsoft HLS SDK for WIndows Referenced.

My code very simple as you can see:

```
 private async Task GetVideoById(string videoId)
        {
            try
            {
                var hlsUri = new Uri("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8");

                var hlsSource = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync(hlsUri);

                if (hlsSource.Status == AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationStatus.Success)
                {
                    DmPlayer.SetMediaStreamSource(hlsSource.MediaSource);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex;
            }
        }
```

My XAML:

```
<playerFramework:MediaPlayer x:Name="DmPlayer"
                                     Grid.Row="0"
                                     MinWidth="400"
                                     MinHeight="200"
                                     MaxHeight="400"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     AutoPlay="True"
                                     IsFullScreenEnabled="True"
                                     IsFullScreenVisible="True"
                                     IsPlayPauseVisible="True"
                                     IsTimeElapsedVisible="True"
                                     IsTimeRemainingVisible="True"
                                     IsVolumeVisible="False"
                                     SeekWhileScrubbing="True"
                                     Stretch="Uniform"
                                     d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <playerFramework:MediaPlayer.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="PlayerTransform" />
        </playerFramework:MediaPlayer.RenderTransform>
        <playerFramework:MediaPlayer.Plugins>
        </playerFramework:MediaPlayer.Plugins>
    </playerFramework:MediaPlayer>
```

Edit:

Cmd > systeminfo:

Host Name:                 DESKTOP-7T9I942

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro N

OS Version:                10.0.10586 N/A Build 10586

Comment: I tested your code in my side, it works well. Have you tried [Adaptive streaming sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AdaptiveStreaming) form Microsoft? Although it doesn't use Player Framework, but it also uses `AdaptiveMediaSource`.

Comment: I am running Windows 10 Build 10586 and you? did you install Microsoft latest update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to my Build... 
I have tried this code on a laptop running Windows 10 Build 10240 and another running Windows 10 Build 10569 and I had no issues.  This happened after I did the Windows 10 threshold 2 update, so I recommend to NOT do that update.